# Why the difference in displaying my webcam image across browsers?

Tags: javascript, image, cross-browser, autoresize, partial-page-refresh

I have an IP webcam and upload an image to a weather service. I then capture that image to display in my webpage. In order to do that I searched for some code that would refresh the image without refreshing the page. I found some code (sorry, I don't know who to acknowledge) that I adapted ……..

```
    <script> 
    var reimg
    window.onload=function () {
    reimg=document.getElementById('re')
    setInterval(function () {
    reimg.src=reimg.src.replace(/\?.*/,function () {
    return '?'+new Date()
    })
    },60000)
    }
    </script>
```

The next bit is, to a great extent, probably overkill but I have been trying to get it to work (how I want it to look) on all browsers...

```
    <iframe frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 border=0 width="360" height="270" style="overflow:
    hidden;border:0;margin:0;width:360px;height:270px;max-width:100%;max-height:100%" 
    src="http://icons.wunderground.com/webcamramdisk/g/l/Gluepack/1/current.jpg?" id="re" scrolling="no"
    allowtransparency="true">If you can see this, your browser doesn't understand IFRAME. However, we'll 
    still <A HREF="http://icons.wunderground.com/webcamramdisk/g/l/Gluepack/1/current.jpg">link</A> 
    you to the file.</iframe>
```

It works fine in Firefox, reducing the 640 x 480 original image to fit. However, in IE and Chrome only the centre top part of the image is shown (i.e. the image is not reduced to fit). Is there any additional code required to ensure it displays correctly (i.e. how I want it, reduced to fit) in IE and Chrome or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

How images are displayed is really up to the browser, there is not standard for that. The easiest solution would be to create an HTML file that contains the javascript and a `<img>` tag for the image instead of loading the image directly into the iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var reimg = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

    setInterval(function () {
        reimg.src = reimg.src.replace(/\?.*/, function () {
            return '?'+new Date()
        });
    }, 60000);
};
</script>
<style type="text/css">
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
img { width: 360px; height: 270px; }
</head><body>
    <img src="http://icons.wunderground.com/webcamramdisk/g/l/Gluepack/1/current.jpg?">
</body></html>
```

Save this as "webcam.html" or whatever:

```
<iframe frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 border=0
width="360" height="270" style="overflow: hidden; border:0; 
margin:0; width:360px; height:270px; max-width:100%; max-height:100%" 
src="webcam.html" id="re" scrolling="no"
allowtransparency="true">...</iframe>
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and I understand what you have said. However, as it is a free website, it appears to be conflicting with the controls that they have in place and, instead of my webcam image, a condensed version of one of the advertising banners displayed at the top of the page, is substituted. I have reverted to the original code but you can see what I am trying to do at http://dobrina.bravehost.com

Comment: and if you invoke webcam.html at that location, you'll see the result (can look at the generated source too).